# NoSuchOrganizationException: No Organization exists with the primary key 0

Tags: liferay, primary-key, liferay-6, portal, liferay-theme

We have a portal hosted on Liferay and in that I have created several organizations and locations under a parent organization in Liferay. Now in our custom form portlets we have a drop down for both organizations and locations which display the already available organizations and locations created by me in Liferay.

The issue is that I did an entire new setup as my WebSphere Application Server had expired and after setting up our portal, now I am not able to see the locations and organizations in the drop down of any form and if I submit any form without selecting the organization/location it throws an error in the log -

> ERROR [WebContainer : 9][render_portlet_jsp:154]
>   com.liferay.portal.NoSuchOrganizationException: No Organization exists
>   with the primary key 0

Below is the snapshot of the structure of my locations and organizations where Reliance Power is the parent organizations and it has 8 suborhganizations.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

- Go to Control Panel (With admin user)
- Server Administration
- On Resources Tab find something like that "Regenrate all indexes ..."
- Execut it

I hope this helps